# How to make an heterogeneous container?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, unions

I'm trying to make an heterogeneous container.

So there can be any number of structs `S1, S2 ... SN` (just 2 in the example below) and a wrapper that can contain each one in a tagged union.

The structs have the same methods but do not implement an interface (They have to be POD or at least literal types to be part of a union).

I want to find a way to avoid the ugly macro below. It's the only way I've found to avoid duplicate code. I tried messing with template but I'm not experimented enough.

I know I can use a class hierarchy with virtual methods but this is an experiment. I looking for a solution that do not use the Boost library and is compatible with c++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct S1 {
  void f1() const { cout << "S1:f1" << endl; }
  void f2() const { cout << "S1:f2" << endl; }
};

struct S2 {
  void f1() const { cout << "S2:f1" << endl; }
  void f2() const { cout << "S2:f2" << endl; }
};

struct Wrapper {
  enum class Type : size_t {
    T1,
    T2
  } type;
  union {
    const S1 s1;
    const S2 s2;
  };
  Wrapper(S1 s1): type{Type::T1}, s1{s1} {}
  Wrapper(S2 s2): type{Type::T2}, s2{s2} {}

  #define FUNC(func_name) void func_name() {\
    switch (type) {\
      case Type::T1: s1.func_name(); break;\
      case Type::T2: s2.func_name(); break;\
    }\
  }

  FUNC(f1)
  // void f1() {
  //   switch (type) {
  //     case Type::T1: s1.f1(); break;
  //     case Type::T2: s2.f1(); break;
  //   }
  // }
  FUNC(f2)
  // void f2() {
  //   switch (type) {
  //     case Type::T1: s1.f2(); break;
  //     case Type::T2: s2.f2(); break;
  //   }
  // }
};

int main() {
  vector<Wrapper> vec;
  vec.push_back(Wrapper(S1()));
  vec.push_back(Wrapper(S2()));

  for (Wrapper w : vec) {
    w.f1();
    w.f2();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::any`?

Comment: Like I said I'd prefer not to use c++14/17 features. It would be of any help anyway because I want to be able to call the structs' methods from the wrapper, but don't want to repeat the switch-case for every one of them.

Comment: If you want to avoid switch then you need polymorphism but you want to avoid that. You also want to construct different functions with different names and that is not the purpose of templates. I'm afraid you can't do it more elegantly.